# Running a Desktop Application on a Server that accesses a network and the files

Tags: docker, containers, desktop-application, windows-server

I have created a small desktop application that reads in two csv and produces one csv. I would like to run this on a server that it will read in two csv from two different locations on the network (let's say folder 1 and folder 2) and saves the output csv somewhere on the network (in folder 3) as well. What I mean by network is that it is Microsoft Servers used for remote work, so people's files can be synced and databases are stored. When the output in folder 3 is created, an email will then be sent to someone (this is not super important right now). I would like this to automatically run every 5 minutes (reading in 2 csv & produce 1 output csv). What should I look into to get this done? I looked at Docker Containers and know how to set one up, but is that considered running on a server? I am not too sure where to start... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am able to get the program to run on a Container. My program allows drag & drop of the csv files, so no problems there. I can also tweak the code to read from a specific folder by providing the path. But on a server/Container? That is what I'm stuck on.

Edited on 2/20/23 12:16PM to clarify some parts that are too vague.

Comment: There's a lot of details you've left out here.  Where is "a location on the network"?  How would you read or write these files?  How would it run on the server, without necessarily having a desktop available?  It's possible the application you want to build will look completely different from your existing desktop application.  Docker may or may not be part of the solution, but it won't address this very different environment on its own.  I'd suggest building a standalone application in an environment that makes sense, then deploying it in containers if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the questions! I have added some clarifications in my original text. As for the current application, it is very very simple, just a backend.py file and a gui.py file that creates the UI. The environment is on Microsoft Servers.